# Get user privileges of a Jenkins user using python

Tags: python, jenkins, python-requests

Can I know the user privileges of a Jenkins user using python.

This is what I have been able to do so far.

```
import jenkins

file1 = open('instances.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
 

# Strips the newline character
for line in Lines:
    #print(line.strip())
    url = "http://"+str(line.strip())
    print(url)
    try:
        server = jenkins.Jenkins(url, username='', password='')
        version = server.get_version()
        print(version)
    except:
        pass
```

The following just lists Jenkins version.

Comment: `server.get_whoami()`?

Comment: I guess it only lists user logged in but not the priveleges.

Comment: in that case it would seem this package doesn’t offer that functionality